# URL Parameter repeats when redirect using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im facing a strange issue. Im trying to redirect from the current page to another using the javascript way as follows with parameters append

If my URL is **myurl.com**

When I execute the following javascript even from Developer Console

```
window.location.href = 'details/page.aspx?k=10';
```

The page loads fine but there is two parameters at the URL

The loaded URL is

> http://myurl.com/details/page.aspx?k=10&&k=10

So why its repeating strangely?

Ive URL rewriting in web.config for HTTP - HTTPS switching of certain pages

Comment: There must be something wrong with code. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Its an ASP.NET application. I tried the above javascript from developer console. Even its showing as parameters repeated

Comment: It seems that you've additional redirect at backend. Have you tried to debug network in Chrome WebTools? But debug it with "preserve log" option enabled.

Comment: I assume this is because of your relative- instead of an absolute path starting with an `/`. Have you tried it with an starting slash?

Comment: Sorry.. I missed an important thing.. There is URL rewriting in web.config for http https switching

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem

Unfortunately thats a problem from URL rewriting. I missed to specify

> appendQueryString="false"

in action field of URL rewriting in web.config which is added now and solved the issue.